# instanceVariables in traits smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, traits, pharo

Is it possible to use instanceVariables when using traits in Pharo Smalltalk?

```
Trait named: #Personnel
uses:{}
category: 'Test'
```

and I would like to add some variables that other Classes can use from these traits. Is this possible in Smalltalk?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. 
Traits are **stateless** composable units, which in plain means: no attributes, just methods.

For a more detailed explanation, you can take a look at: http://scg.unibe.ch/archive/papers/Scha03aTraits.pdf

Comment: However there are prototypes of stateful traits as well: http://scg.unibe.ch/archive/papers/Verw11bFlexibleObjectLayouts.pdf